# Fabric - sudo -u

Tags: python, django, sudo, fabric

I'm using fabric to launch a command on a remote server.
I'd like to launch this command as a different user (neither the one connected nor root).

```
def colstat():
  run('python manage.py collectstatic --noinput')
```

Trying

```
def colstat():
  sudo('-u www-data python manage.py collectstatic --noinput')
```

Oviously this won't work because -u will be considered as a command and not an option of sudo

> out: /bin/bash: -u : command not found

(**www-data** is the user which should run the command)
How can I use **www-data** to run my command from Fabric ?

Comment: Worth noticing that I think an application should not require sudo privilege. I think we should always be able to deal with stuff like ACLs.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Judging from the [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.sudo):

```
sudo('python manage.py collectstatic --noinput', user='www-data')
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see [this part](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/api/core/operations.html?highlight=sudo#fabric.operations.sudo) in the doc. Especially since it's documented with almost my example case :( Sorry